# copy file from ubuntu to windows server with terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-server-2012

I want to copy  file from **Ubuntu** operating system into windows server without program,
i used  **ssh** ,but it did not  work.

Comment: Easy way of doing this on a windows machine would be to use winscp (a sort of FTP server which uses SSH to transfer the files) SFTP if im not misstaken. This is installed on all windows OS , just type in winscp* fill in the ssh data and you can connect to the host. and copy paste as normally you would with a windows explorer screen. 

A small assumption I have to make based on your question: "The windows machine is your OS , and Ubuntu is your remote desktop."

Comment: thanks,but i think you did not understand my mean,i have linux machin, i want to copy from linux machin to windows server

Comment: **1-** I believe this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network. **2-** Check this link: [Transfer file to Windows server from Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677773/transfer-file-to-windows-server-from-ubuntu) _(this is a possibility of duplicate question)_